# why I have to use $('#id')[0].srollHeight instead of $('#id').srollHeight

Tags: jquery, css

I have a overflow element

```
<div class="conversation" id="conversation"  data-pUserName="'.$p_username.'"  data-userName="'.$username.'" >
</div>
```

and try to position the scroll bar at the bottom by default

```
$("#conversation").scrollTop($("#conversation")[0].scrollHeight);
```

the problem is that I have to use `$("#conversation")[0].scrollHeight` in order to make it work even i select element by ID, and I tried to use `$("#conversation").scrollHeight` and it's not working.  the "[0]" I think is the short cut of `.get(0)`, and return the first element of the selected element(I think only when the element is a class and would return the first one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `scrollHeight` is not a jQuery method, it's a DOM property.

So you need a DOM object in order to get `scrollheight` value.

`$("#conversation")` will get you jQuery object, so `$("#conversation")[0]` help you to convert this jQuery object to a DOM element in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're working with a jQuery object (`$('#id')`), and `scrollHeight` is a property of the DOM object, not the jQuery object. You could also use the jQuery `prop` function: `$('#id').prop('scrollHeight')`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `[0]` because when you use jQuery, you aren't actually selecting the element. You are selecting a jQuery object that contains that element. Because `scrollHeight` is not a property of the jQuery object, but a property of the actual element, you need to use `[0]` to refer to the actual element.